Vercel Cannot deserialize Firebase Private_key
I'm attempting to host a python flask app on Vercel with a google firestore back end. I have an app which looks like this:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import json

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio
import os


#to run: flask run
app = Flask(__name__)

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db, initialize_app

# Fetch and fix the private key from the environment variable
raw_private_key = os.environ.get("PRIVATE_KEY")
if raw_private_key:
    private_key = raw_private_key.replace("\\n", "\n")  # Convert to actual newlines
    print("private key is good")
    print(repr(private_key[:50]))
else:
    print("PRIVATE_KEY environment variable is not set.")
    private_key = ""

firebase_credentials = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": os.environ.get("PROJECT_ID"),
    "private_key_id": os.environ.get("PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
    "private_key": private_key,
    "client_email": os.environ.get("CLIENT_EMAIL"),
    "client_id": os.environ.get("CLIENT_ID"),
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get("CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL"),
    "universe_domain": os.environ.get("UNIVERSE_DOMAIN")
}

# Initialize the Firebase app
# Load Firebase credentials from environment variables

# Initialize Firebase app with the credentials and database URL
print(f"Private key length: {len(firebase_credentials["private_key"])}")
print(f"Private key snippet: {firebase_credentials["private_key"][:35]}...{firebase_credentials["private_key"][-35:]}")
try:
    # Initialize Firebase with corrected credentials
    cred = credentials.Certificate(firebase_credentials)
    initialize_app(cred, {
        'databaseURL': 'https://doomblade-b08ea-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'
    })
    print("Firebase initialized successfully.")
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Failed to initialize Firebase: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")

# Load data from Firebase
def fetch_data_from_firebase(path):
    ref = db.reference(path)
    return ref.get()

# Get data for 'home' and 'EDH'
data = fetch_data_from_firebase('home')
EDH_data = fetch_data_from_firebase('EDH')

# Now 'data' and 'EDH_data' contain the same structure as before
print(data)
print(EDH_data)

    
@app.route('/')
def index():
    formats = [list(d.keys())[0] for d in data]  # Extract formats from the data
    formats = ["standard"] + [item for item in formats if item !="standard"]
    return render_template('index.html', formats=formats)

@app.route('/plot', methods=['POST'])
def plot():
    print("/plot run")
    selected_format = request.form['format']
    
    # Find the selected data
    selected_data = next((item[selected_format] for item in data if selected_format in item), None)
    if not selected_data:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Data not found for the selected format.'})

    # Extract X and Y data
    x_data = selected_data[0]
    y_data = selected_data[1]

    # Create a histogram using Plotly

    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=y_data, y=x_data,
                             orientation='h',
                             marker_color="black",
                      hovertemplate='%{label}: %{value:,.0f}<extra></extra>' )])
    fig.update_layout(title=f'What dies to Doomblade in {selected_format}?', 
                      xaxis_title='Number of Creatures that Die to Spell', 
                      yaxis_title='Card Names', 
                      xaxis=dict(tickformat=',d'))
    
    # Convert the plot to JSON format
    graph_json = pio.to_json(fig)

    return jsonify(graph_json)

and a Vercel Environment variable setup which looks like this:
PRIVATE_KEY = -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAsomeothercharactersxrbf59Tas....V\\nc5WAvQbsomeothercharacters0fhlM3Sxm\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n
I have my other vercel environment variables setup in a similar fashion, but they're all single line and I dont think that is where the problem lies.
The error I keep getting is:
Failed to initialize Firebase: Failed to initialize a certificate credential. Caused by: "('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, the provided password may be incorrect, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=503841036, lib=60, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>])"
[ERROR] ValueError: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure to initialize the SDK by calling initialize_app().
I suspect the problem has something to do with the way my variable is formatted or the way I'm calling it in my flask app, but I haven't been able to parse (get it?) out how to fix it. I'd love any and all suggestions.
